# C# Get Logged in user email address from logged in user in Active Directory, IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

I am developing an MVC app and I would like to auto login users into the system by retrieving their email address from Active Directory, use that email address to find a user in my database, if found log them into the system. The Idea is for the system to not force the user to input login details after already logging into their workstation that is setup on a work domain/Active Directory.

Please help me with pointers on this as I've tried most approaches described in many threads.

- I've set my IIS app pool to Network Service
- ASP.NET Impersonation is disabled..
- I've enabled Load User Profile in app pool -> Advanced Settings

When I use the code below, the search fails:

```
using ( System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate() )
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain );

    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( ctx, User.Identity.Name );

    Response.Write( "User: " + User.Identity.Name );
    Response.Write( user.EmailAddress );
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Error: `The (&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=)(distinguishedName=)(name=))) search filter is invalid.`

Can someone please point me into the right direction of what I am trying to achieve? Am I approaching my requirement wrongly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on {, what is the value of `User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: @BriansaysReinstateMonica The value is blank...

Comment: Having the same idea here and the same issue. I have an issue understanding why is it required from user to "re-login" to retrieve his own information from AD after already being authenticated. Please keep this thread updated.

Comment: P.S.: I have an alternative login through LDAP where I can get all of the user information (first name, last name, phone, email, groups, etc.). Why can't I get it from IIS?

Answer (score 1):

For users to be logged in automatically, you need to use Windows Authentication. For that to work, there are a few prerequisites:

1. The users must be logged into Windows with the account they will use to authenticate to your website.
2. Your website must be added to the Trusted Sites in Internet Options in Windows (or considered an "Intranet Site") so that IE and Chrome will automatically send the credentials. Firefox has its own setting called `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`.
3. Your server must be joined to a domain with a trust to the domain of the users (usually it's the same domain).

If all those things are true, then you can follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/#windows-server-2012-or-windows-server-2012-r2) to install the Windows Authentication feature in IIS (depending on your version). If you're using IIS Express for running it locally, then you can skip this step on your development machine.

Then enable the use of Windows Authentication in your website by modifying your web.config file. Add this under the `<system.web>` tag:

```xml
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

And add this under `<system.webServer>`:

```xml
<security>
    <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
    </authentication>
</security>
```

Then, as long as your website is trusted by the browser (step 2 above), you will automatically be logged in. The username of the logged on user will be `User.Identity.Name`. All of the code you show will work, however you don't need to call `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CheckUserInGroup(string group)
    {
        string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServer"];
        string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUserName"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"];
        bool result = false;
        SecureString securePwd = null;
        if (password != null)
        {
            securePwd = new SecureString();
            foreach (char chr in password.ToCharArray())
            {
                securePwd.AppendChar(chr);
            }
        }
        try
        {  
            ActiveDirectory adConnectGroup = new ActiveDirectory(serverName, userName, securePwd);

            SearchResultEntry groupResult = adConnectGroup.GetEntryByCommonName(group);

            Group grp = new Group(adConnectGroup, groupResult);

            SecurityPrincipal userPrincipal = grp.Members.Find(sp => sp.SAMAccountName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());

            if (userPrincipal != null)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I believe there are many ways on how we can retrieve AD users from C# MVC. http://www.codedigest.com/posts/5/get-user-details-from-active-directory-in-aspnet-mvc please take a look at this good example using the galactic API(free and open source package).

Comment: I don't want to specify my Username and Password to connect to Active Directory. I would like to get the configured email address of a user that is currently logged in onto a given workstation. Then use that email address/username to find a user in my database.

Comment: Hi @Morgs, for username and password to connect to active directory. you can try to ask network guy to create specific credential for your system. or you can check this out. https://forums.asp.net/t/1806248.aspx?Active+Directory+Authencation+without+using+Password+